# How can I find large irreducible polynomials over $\mathbf{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm working on a cryptography algorithm. We need $GF(2^n)$ for large n. Therefore we are looking for large irreducible polynomials over $\mathbf{Z}_2$. Especially we want trinomial and n~65536. I tried to use mathematica but it's too slow.

Comment: Good question. Some large irreducibles might be tabulated somewhere.

Comment: Do you need many such polynomials, or just a few?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lidl and Niederreiter give an explicit infinite family of irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb F_2[x]$ of arbitrary high degree. For any $k\ge 1$ the polynomial
$$
p_k(X)=X^{2\cdot3^k}+X^{3^k}+1\in \Bbb F_2[X]
$$
is irreducible (these are trinomials, as you wanted).

Comment: Thanks! but the nearest $2\times 3^k$ is 39366, which is not so close

Comment: I thought, you wanted (see title) to know "how can I find large irreducible polynomials over $\mathbf{Z}_2$?", and $2\cdot 3^{10}=118098$ is even larger than $65536$. But you can also find a irreducible polynomial $X^{65536}+\cdots $, see [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4757-2226-0_3).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.